# Ranking With Ties and Non Consecutive Rank? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to implement the following code into my own.

Here is the code I'm trying to implement. It's for getting Ranks with ties and the rank is non consecutive after the ties.

```
SET @rnk=0;
SET @rank=0;
SET @curscore=0;

SELECT score,ID,rank FROM (

    SELECT AA.*,BB.ID,
    (@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk,
    (@rank:=IF(@curscore=score,@rank,@rnk)) rank,
    (@curscore:=score) newscore
    FROM (

        SELECT * FROM (

            SELECT COUNT(1) scorecount,score
            FROM scores GROUP BY score

        ) AAA
        ORDER BY score DESC

    ) AA LEFT JOIN scores BB USING (score)

) A;
```

Here is the link to where I got the code from. It's the second answer.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table

My code is below. I swapped "score" with "totalPoints". This is as far as I got.

I am having trouble with two parts of the code.

This line, the BB.ID part.

`SELECT AA.*, BB.ID,`

And this line.

`) AA LEFT JOIN scores BB USING (score)`

I know what the code is doing I just don't know how to replace those parts with my code and tables to get them to work.

```
SET @rnk=0;
SET @rank=0;
SET @curscore=0;

SELECT AA.*, BB.ID,
(@rnk:=@rnk+1) rnk,
(@rank:=IF(@curscore=totalPoints,@rank,@rnk)) rank,
(@curscore:=totalPoints) newPoints
FROM (

    SELECT * FROM (

        SELECT COUNT(1) scorecount, totalPoints FROM (

            #----------start of my code

            SELECT *, (totalWins+(totalPushs*.5)) AS totalPoints, totalWins+totalLost+totalPushs AS totalBets FROM (

                SELECT *, SUM(win) AS totalWins, SUM(lost) AS totalLost, SUM(push) AS totalPushs FROM (

                    SELECT *, (finalResult = 'Winner') AS win, (finalResult = 'Loser') AS lost, (finalResult = 'Push') AS push FROM (

                        SELECT nflp_users.userID, userName, avatar, teamColor,
                        IF (pickID=visitorID, visitorResult, homeResult) AS finalResult
                        FROM nflp_users
                        JOIN nflp_picks
                        ON nflp_users.userID = nflp_picks.userID
                        JOIN nflp_schedule
                        ON nflp_picks.gameID = nflp_schedule.gameID
                    ) x

                ) x
                GROUP BY userID

            ) x

            #----------end of my code

        ) x GROUP BY totalPoints

    ) AAA
    ORDER BY totalPoints DESC

) AA LEFT JOIN scores BB USING (score)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you post your table schemas, sample data and desired output. In other words the usual drill when you ask to help with query.